# How to quickly merge two images using php

Tags: php, image, store

I am making an online store so, I need to merge the design image with the mockup image and because of having a lot of mockups the merging process tooks too long time about 5min for each design. I'm looking for a quicker function from the one that I am using. this my php function:

```
function createimageinstantly($img1, $img2, $color, $randF){
  // check the file format
  if(end(explode(".", $img2)) == "png"){$source = imagecreatefrompng($img2);}else{$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($img2);}
  if(end(explode(".", $img1)) == "png"){$destination = imagecreatefrompng($img1);}else{$destination = imagecreatefromjpeg($img1);}
  //to resize the second image start

  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img2);
  list($width1, $height1) = getimagesize($img1);
  $percent = ((intval($width1 * 100 / $width) * 0.34) / 100);
  // Calculate new sizes
  $newwidth = $width * $percent;
  $newheight = $height * $percent;
  $chupon = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
  imagealphablending($chupon, false);
  imagesavealpha($chupon,true);
  $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($chupon, 255, 255, 255, 127);
  imagefilledrectangle($chupon, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $transparent);
  imagecopyresized($chupon, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
  // merge images
  imagecopy($destination, $chupon, (imagesx($destination) / 2) - (imagesx($chupon) / 2), (imagesy($destination) / 2) - (imagesy($chupon) / 2  + imagesy($chupon) / 4), 0, 0, imagesx($chupon), imagesy($chupon));
  //header("Content-type: image/png");
  $file_name = end(explode("/", $img2));
  $file_name = explode(".", $file_name);
  //Output the image
  if(end(explode(".", $img1)) == "png"){imagepng($destination, "../uploades/show/".$file_name[0].$randF."_".$color.".".$file_name[1]);}else{imagejpeg($destination, "../uploades/show/".$file_name[0].$randF."_".$color.".".$file_name[1]);}
}
```

It tooks the design image in $img1 and the mockup image in $img2, the $color and $randF are just a variables to change the name of the output image.
In this process I merge the design image after resizing it to fit on top of the mockup image in order to produce something like:
[image: this is an exemple of what it should be like]

I hope you can help me !
These are an example for the images that I am using:
the mockup:
[image: mockup image]

the design image(I just got it from internet)
[image: design image]

Comment: I have a question. Could you describe how the merge works? I see that you have two images and a background. but then you add the first image to the background and the background to the second image, right?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but I think so !

Comment: I noticed also that, when I was trying to speed up the merging process I used a transparent mockup image and I noticed that the background of the mockup turned to white every single time I tryed that.

Comment: you could use `imagefill` instead of `imagefillrectangle`. Also you could use `imagescale` and `imagecopy` instead of `imagecopyresized`

Comment: you could also get rid of `imagesx` and `imagesy`, because you already got `getimagesize`. Or create some variables with the values of the images size from `imagesx` and `imagesy` so you dont have to call the function over and over

Comment: also why the background is never transparent, because you copy the transperent `$chupon` onto the white `$destination`

Comment: could you add the raw images, so i could test stuff on my own?

Comment: you can test this: https://github.com/Intervention/image

Comment: I added the raw images, can you test the way you are using for me ? and send it as an anwser just to make it easy for me ! thanks @Play_it ! I hope you fix it, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some simplyfications. For example i use the mockup as background and scale the design itself instead of coping it to the smaller empty image.

> Important: the output needs to be `.png` because ony so you get a transperent background. Also use `.png` for better transparent results for the overlaing

```php
<?php
function createimageinstantly($design, $mockup){
    // check the file format
    if(end(explode(".", $design)) == "png"){$designi = imagecreatefrompng($design);}else{$designi = imagecreatefromjpeg($design);}
    if(end(explode(".", $mockup)) == "png"){$mockupi = imagecreatefrompng($mockup);}else{$mockupi = imagecreatefromjpeg($mockup);}
    //to resize the second image start

    list($width1, $height1) = getimagesize($mockup);

    imagealphablending($designi, false);
    imagesavealpha($designi, true);
    imagecolortransparent($designi, imagecolorallocate($designi, 255, 255, 255));

    $designi = imagescale($designi, $width1 * 0.34);
    $newwidth = imagesx($designi);
    $newheight = imagesy($designi);

    // imagealphablending($mockupi, false);
    imagesavealpha($mockupi, true);
    imagefill($mockupi, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($mockupi, 0, 0, 0, 127));

    // merge images
    imagecopy($mockupi, $designi, ($width1 - $newwidth) / 2, ($height1 - $newheight * 3/2) / 2, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight);

    // $file_name = end(explode("/", $design));
    // $file_name = explode(".", $file_name);
    //Output the image
    imagepng($mockupi, __DIR__."/test.png");
}

createimageinstantly(
    __DIR__."/design-png-hd-graphic-design-transparent-1590.png",
    __DIR__."/otHl3.png"
);
?>
```

Info: for me the code only took 1 second to execute and the original did the same. At some point you can't strip down the code enougth to shorten execution time.